# Difference between Ajax and Dojo

Tags: ajax, dojo

can you explain to me the difference between Ajax and Dojo?

Answer (score 3):

Ajax is the technology (Asynchronous Javascript And XML (actually it's often JSON, HTML, Plaintext instead of XML)) and Dojo is a JavaScript framework like Mootools, JQuery, Prototype.

You really do not want to use Ajax without a framework as it'll require much more code and make your code less readable.